# SQL Performance: LIKE vs IN

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

In my logging database I have serveral qualifiers specifying the logged action. A few of them are built like 'Item.Action' e.g. 'Customer.Add'. I wonder which approach will be faster if I want to get all logging items that starts with 'Customer.':

```sql
SELECT * FROM log WHERE action LIKE 'Customer.%'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM log WHERE action IN ('Customer.Add', 'Customer.Delete', 'Customer.Update', 'Customer.Export', 'Customer.Import')
```

I use PostgreSql.

Comment: Check the execution plan using `explain analyze`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html

Comment: Side note - you should not worry about performance till you actually have performance problems. Use a simpler/cleaner query, test it for performance. If there are problems THEN try to do something with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on indexes on `log` table. Most likely - queries will have the same performance. To check - use `explain` or `explain analyze`. Queries with the same execution plan (output of `explain`) will have the same performance.

Comment: I checked my queries with explain and found that there really is only a small difference. In my case LIKE is about 5% faster. Thanks!